# How to get Terminal to show screen dimensions while being resized in Jammy

Tags: compiz, resize

When I resize a terminal window in Jammy (22.04.1), the terminal doesn't show the new size.

I've installed the CompvizConfig Setting Manager and the extended plugins, and turned on Utility->Resize Info, which did the trick in the past.  It doesn't seem to do anything at all in Jammy.

I turned on "Show ResizeInfo for all windows" and this doesn't seem to work for any other kind of window either.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 runs by default a customized version of Gnome Shell. Compiz-config therefore is not applicable. You can, however, still install the Unity desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, as well as not being able to alt-tab between windows (focus would remain in the initial window). The root cause seems to be the switch to Wayland from X, as described in https://kbpdfstudio.qoppa.com/alt-tab-does-not-work-on-ubuntu-22-04/ . Disabling Wayland this way took care of it for me. (It would seem Wayland has some ways to go before it's ready for prime time; I have noticed several other glitches before reverting to X)